# Set template from typename

Tags: c++, stdvector, typeid

I'm given the typename of some type. Is there a way to get the typename name of an std::vector of this type?

Something like:

```
std::string GetVectorTypename(std::string const& tname) { 
 /* return the typeid of an std::vector of tname's.

  In this example, I want this to return typeid(std::vector<double>).name() */
}

int main() {
 const std::string tname = typeid(double).name();

 const std::string vec_tname = GetVectorTypename(tname);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to write `const std::string typename = stuff` as `typename` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: quite correct -- i'll change the variable name.

Comment: Not sure this can be done with `typeid`, can't you use templates?

Comment: This type might not exist, so it might not have its name, are you assuming the type is instantiated?

Comment: In this simple example templates are probably the obvious choice.  However, I ran into this problem using boost::any's, which I'm using to avoid templates

Comment: There is no run-time way of doing this. Template instantiation happens at compile time.

Comment: You would need a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` that maps `typeid(double).name()` to `typeid(std::vector<double>).name()`.

Comment: No the type will be instantiated later.   The context is an ODE solver whose constructor knows the type of the 'state' variable.  A 'integrator' function then returns a vector of this type at specified times after integrating the ODE.